# Sending email activation(confirmation) link when user UPDATING email address in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-6, activation-function

How can I resend my activation account email to my user once the user update the email address.

Email address should not be changed in the db until user click on the confirmation link

following is my update function for an user in my usercontroller(only the function body included)

```
if($request->hasFile('propic'))
           {
                $this->validate($request, [
                    'name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
                    'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:5', 'max:255'],
                    'mobile' => ['required', 'numeric','min:9','regex:/\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|3[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$/'],
                    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email,'.$setting->id.''],
                    'propic' => ['required','image','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg','max:2048'],
                ],$request->all());

                $imageName = time().'.'.$request->propic->extension();  
                $request->propic->move(public_path('propics'), $imageName);
                $setting->propic=$imageName;
                $setting->name=$request->input('name');
                $setting->last_name=$request->input('last_name');
                $setting->mobile=$request->input('mobile');
                $setting->email=$request->input('email');
                $setting->update();
                return Redirect::back()->with('success',__('sentence.User updated successfully'));  
           }
```

and following is my update user form

```
<form action="{{ route('settings.update',$user->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row mt-5">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                @if($user->propic != 'user-pic.png')
    <button type="submit" name="resetphoto" class="btn btn-warning  pull-right">{{ __('sentence.Remove Profile Pic') }}</button>
@endif
                    <img src="/propics/{{$user->propic}}" alt="Profile Pic" id="profile_pic_display" class="mb-3">
                    <input type="file" name="propic" class="form-control">

                    @error('propic')
                    <span class="help-block" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                <!-- <form action="{{ route('settings.update',$user->id) }}" method="POST"> -->
                    @csrf
                    @method('PUT')
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            <div class="form-group field-user-firstname required">
                                <label class="control-label"
                                       for="user-firstname">{{ __('sentence.First Name') }}</label>
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
                                       name="name" value="{{$user->name}}" autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group field-user-lastname required">
                                <label class="control-label" for="user-lastname">{{ __('sentence.Last Name') }}</label>
                                <input id="last_name" type="text"
                                       class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="last_name"
                                       value="{{$user->last_name}}" autocomplete="last_name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group field-user-mobile required">
                                <label class="control-label" for="user-mobile">{{ __('sentence.Mobile') }}</label><br/>
                                <input id="mobile_1" type="tel"
                                       class="form-control @error('mobile') is-invalid @enderror" name="mobile"
                                       value="{{$user->mobile}}" style="min-width:398px;" autocomplete="mobile"
                                       autofocus>

                                @error('mobile')
                                <span class="help-block" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group field-user-email required">
                                <label class="control-label" for="user-email">{{ __('sentence.Email') }}</label>
                                <input id="email_" type="email"
                                       class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email"
                                       value="{{$user->email}}" autocomplete="email" >

                                @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="form-group pull-right">
                                <button type="submit"
                                        class="btn btn-default">{{ __('sentence.Cancel') }}</button>
                                <button type="submit"
                                        class="btn btn-default subscribe px-5">{{ __('sentence.Update') }}</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </form>
```

Currently i'm sending activation link to user email when the user is registering, but I'm struggling to do it when an existing user is trying to update email address..

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear because you're working in a box here and haven't given us the full picture. If the intention is to ensure that the email cannot **unless they've activated**, then re-send them the activation email and **confirm** the new address upon activation, then you're missing some logic here.

Any way that you look at it, you need to store a reference to what the email should be somewhere. Either a column, such as `pending_email` on the table, or it's own table, such as `pending_changes` for instance.

In your `boot` method of your `User` model you can watch for the `updating` event and dispatch a job from there to re-send the activation email and halt the change of the email address:

```
public static function boot() 
{
    parent::boot();

    static::updating(function ($model) {
        if ($model->isDirty('email') && $model->activated_at === null) {
            $model->email = $model->getOriginal('email');
            dispatch (new SendActivationEmail($model));
        }
    });
}
```

Now you can append to that `updating` event to see if they're activating and have a `pending_email`:

```
static::updating(function ($model) {
    if ($model->isDirty('activated_at') && $model->pending_email) {
        $model->email = $model->pending_email;
        $model->pending_email = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: no, assume user need to change the initially registered email after the registration, then the user should receive a new activation email to the updated email and untill then the old email address should not be changed.

Comment: @VolkaDimitrev That is exactly what is happening here.